# How to keep the blocks individual with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning JavaScript and still struggling in some parts. I am trying to make the blocks in this piece of code individual with their own colors so later one I can figure how to add pictures to each block, but it is not working as after only 3 loops the colors disappear and they became all black. I would be very grateful for any help on how to make every block individual and keep their colors. 
Please see the code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Slot Machine</title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="2000"></canvas>

  <script>
    var game = {
      tickNumber: 0,
      timer: null,
      board: [
        "####################",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "####################"
      ],
      tick: function() {
        game.tickNumber++;
        snake.move();
        graphics.drawGame();
        game.timer = window.setTimeout("game.tick()", 500);
      }
    };
    var snake = {
      parts: [{
          x: 2,
          y: 2,
          color: "green"
        },
        {
          x: 2,
          y: 6,
          color: "red"
        },
        {
          x: 2,
          y: 10,
          color: "blue"
        },
        {
          x: 2,
          Y: 14,
          color: "yellow"
        },
        {
          x: 2,
          Y: 16,
          color: "grey"
        }
      ],
      facing: "S",
      nextLocation: function() {
        var snakeHead = snake.parts[0];
        var targetX = snakeHead.x;
        var targetY = snakeHead.y;

        targetY = snake.facing == "S" ? targetY + 4 : targetY;
        if (targetY >= 24) {
          targetY = 2;
        }
        return {
          x: targetX,
          y: targetY
        };
      },
      move: function() {
        var location = snake.nextLocation();
        snake.parts.unshift(location);
        snake.parts.pop();
      }
    };

    var graphics = {
      canvas: document.getElementById("canvas"),
      squareSize: 20,
      squarePic: 60,

      drawBoard: function(ctx) {
        var currentYoffset = 0;
        game.board.forEach(function checkLine(line) {
          line = line.split('');
          var currentXoffset = 0;
          line.forEach(function checkCharacter(character) {
            if (character == '#') {
              ctx.fillStyle = "black";
              ctx.fillRect(currentXoffset, currentYoffset, graphics.squareSize, graphics.squareSize);
            }
            currentXoffset += graphics.squareSize;
          });
          currentYoffset += graphics.squareSize;
        });
      },

      drawSnake: function(ctx) {
        snake.parts.forEach(function drawPart(part) {
          var partXlocation = part.x * graphics.squareSize;
          var partYlocation = part.y * graphics.squareSize;
          var coloracao = part.color;

          ctx.fillStyle = coloracao;
          ctx.fillRect(partXlocation, partYlocation, graphics.squarePic, graphics.squarePic);
        });
      },
      drawGame: function() {
        var ctx = graphics.canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, graphics.canvas.width, graphics.canvas.height);
        graphics.drawBoard(ctx);
        graphics.drawSnake(ctx);
      }
    };

    graphics.drawGame();
    var gameControl = {
      startGame: function() {
        game.tick();
      }
    };
    gameControl.startGame();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the move function in your snake. You are replacing parts object with the new location which has just x and y and no color property.

Ideally to move the snake, you should just move the head and then update rest of the body to move one part up. I've updated your move function where you can see this algorithm.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Slot Machine</title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="2000"></canvas>

  <script>
    var game = {
      tickNumber: 0,
      timer: null,
      board: [
        "####################",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "#                  #",
        "####################"
      ],
      tick: function() {
        game.tickNumber++;
        snake.move();
        graphics.drawGame();
        game.timer = window.setTimeout("game.tick()", 500);
      }
    };
    var snake = {
      parts: [{
          x: 2,
          y: 2,
          color: "green"
        },
        {
          x: 2,
          y: 6,
          color: "red"
        },
        {
          x: 2,
          y: 10,
          color: "blue"
        },
        {
          x: 2,
          Y: 14,
          color: "yellow"
        },
        {
          x: 2,
          Y: 16,
          color: "grey"
        }
      ],
      facing: "S",
      nextLocation: function() {
        var snakeHead = snake.parts[0];
        var targetX = snakeHead.x;
        var targetY = snakeHead.y;

        targetY = snake.facing == "S" ? targetY + 4 : targetY;
        if (targetY >= 24) {
          targetY = 2;
        }
        return {
          x: targetX,
          y: targetY
        };
      },
      move: function() {
        var location = snake.nextLocation();
        var prevX = snake.parts[0].x;
        var prevY = snake.parts[0].y;
        snake.parts[0].x = location.x;
        snake.parts[0].y = location.y;
        for(var i = 1; i < snake.parts.length; i++) {
          var currentX = snake.parts[i].x;
          var currentY = snake.parts[i].y;
          snake.parts[i].x = prevX;
          snake.parts[i].y = prevY;
          prevX = currentX;
          prevY = currentY; 
        }
      }
    };

    var graphics = {
      canvas: document.getElementById("canvas"),
      squareSize: 20,
      squarePic: 60,

      drawBoard: function(ctx) {
        var currentYoffset = 0;
        game.board.forEach(function checkLine(line) {
          line = line.split('');
          var currentXoffset = 0;
          line.forEach(function checkCharacter(character) {
            if (character == '#') {
              ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
              ctx.fillRect(currentXoffset, currentYoffset, graphics.squareSize, graphics.squareSize);
            }
            currentXoffset += graphics.squareSize;
          });
          currentYoffset += graphics.squareSize;
        });
      },

      drawSnake: function(ctx) {
        snake.parts.forEach(function drawPart(part) {
          var partXlocation = part.x * graphics.squareSize;
          var partYlocation = part.y * graphics.squareSize;
          var coloracao = part.color;

          ctx.fillStyle = coloracao;
          ctx.fillRect(partXlocation, partYlocation, graphics.squarePic, graphics.squarePic);
        });
      },
      drawGame: function() {
        var ctx = graphics.canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, graphics.canvas.width, graphics.canvas.height);
        graphics.drawBoard(ctx);
        graphics.drawSnake(ctx);
      }
    };

    graphics.drawGame();
    var gameControl = {
      startGame: function() {
        game.tick();
      }
    };
    gameControl.startGame();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```